# Is this a Ongoing bug?

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I am unable to convert any leads and keep getting this message - Error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0014J00000wOyPyQAK; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, Use one of these records?: []

There are NO Duplicates of the leads and this is happening to all the leads, I cannot convert even one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue that you are facing is a ongoing Known Issue **Bug(W-8560988)** and at this time there is no workaround , other than unchecking the "Alert" notification on "Create" for the Account Duplicate rule, but this will in turn exclude manual creation of Accounts from being flagged by duplicate rules outside of Lead conversion if the only criteria is record type.

We strongly recommend clicking on "Report" on the above Known Issues page. Clicking this button allows you to be notified when the Known Issue is fixed, and all future updates to the status will be posted directly to the Known issues page.

Known issue Link : [Error while converting Leads: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, Use on one of the records?:[]](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwcgAAC/error-while-converting-leads-duplicates_detected-use-on-one-of-the-records)